# Exclude operation symbols in signature

Tags: logic, order-theory, model-theory

We probably know what a signature is, it contains a set $\sigma_{op}$ (the operation symbols), $\sigma_{rel}$ (the relation symbols) and a function $ar:\sigma_{op}\cup\sigma_{rel}\rightarrow\mathbb N$.

If we exclude some operation symbols we get a structure we call reduction. I have a problem finding all four "reductions" of $(\mathbb N,0,1,+,\times,<)$ which are isomorph to the "reductions" of $(\mathbb Q,0,1,-,+,\times)$.

This is an exercise in my logic book in a chapter where Tarskis definition of truth is discussed, I do not see a relation, may you could help me with that.

Comment: You have different signatures for your two structures. Is this intentional?

Comment: This isn't very clear: if you tell us which book, what page, then you have a better chance of getting some help.

Comment: Yes everything is stated in this way. Its on page 23, exercise 2.5 of the following book (unfortunately it is in German, there is english translation): http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~adler/docs/gml.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what you call "reductions" are usually called "reducts".

Now you're looking for four reducts of $(\mathbb{N},0,1,+,\times,<)$ which are isomorphic to reducts of $(\mathbb{Q},0,1,-,+,\times)$. Notice that isomorphism only makes sense for structures in the same signature, so you're going to have to get rid of $<$ and $-$, since these symbols only appear in one of the signatures each.

We're left with the set of symbols $\{0, 1, +, \times\}$. We get one reduct of $(\mathbb{N},0,1,+,\times)$ and $(\mathbb{Q},0,1,+,\times)$ for each subset of this set of symbols. Exactly four of these subsets produce isomorphic structures.

Here's one to get you started: For structures in the empty signature, an isomorphism is just a bijection (there are no operations / relations to respect), so after taking a reduct to the empty signature, any two structures of the same cardinality are isomorphic.

I'm not sure why this is the section on Tarski's definition of truth - I see no connection.

Comment: Ok Thank you, so we found at least two isomorphic reducts, $(\mathbb N)$ with $(\mathbb Q)$ and $(\mathbb N,0,1,+,\times)$ with $(\mathbb Q,0,1,+,\times)$. How can I find out if for exmaple $(\mathbb N,0,1)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Q,0,1$ ?

Comment: Well, what is an isomorphism in a signature with just constants? It has to take $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$ and then...?

Comment: Also, to fully answer the question, once you've found the four isomorphic reducts, you may want to try to prove that none of the other reducts are isomorphic.

Comment: Ok in the case of $(\mathbb N,0,1)$, and $0\rightarrow 0$, $1\rightarrow 1$ then we have a bijective homomorphism = isomorphism. I guess the other isomoprhism are $(\mathbb N,0),(\mathbb N,1)$

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: How can $(\mathbb N, 0, 1, +, \times)$ be isomorhic to $(\mathbb Q, 0, 1, +, \times)$ as you said in the first comment ? Don't we have $\mathbb Q \models \exists y, y + y = 1$ when $\mathbb N$ does not ?